# Use of Mergelyan's theorem to approximate a function that is nearly vanishing on unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $K$ be a proper compact subset of the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Prove that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a polynomial $p(z)$ such that $$|p(z)| \leq \epsilon$$
for $z \in K$ and $p(0)=1$.

My thoughts: Mergelyan's Theorem came to mind, but I could not maintain the condition $p(0)=1$. That is, even if I could construct a function $f(z)$ continuous on $K$ such that $|f(z)|<\epsilon/2$ (for instance) whenever $z \in K$, there is no guarantee that the polynomial approximation $p(z)$ to $f(z)$ has to satisfy $p(0)=1$. How to maintain this condition when Mergelyan is invoked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Applying Mergelyan's Theorem on the zero function is not terribly useful. Given your compact subset of the unit circle, add on a "radius" to it to get a compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Use this as your set to apply Mergelyan's Theorem on. You simply need to do the following:

1. Define a sequence of holomorphic functions $f_n$ that converges uniformly to $0$ on your compact subset of the unit circle and to $1$ at $0$. (Hint for this: think about the Dirac delta function)
2. Show that you can set your "subset of the unit circle with a radius" to have connected complement.

Comment: I would like to offer my proof after some further thought:

Define $K_0 = K \cup \{0\}$. Then $K_0$ is a compact subset of the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$ such that the complement of $K_0$ in the extended complex plane $\mathbb{C}_\infty$ is a connected set. Now define a sequence of functions $f_n(z) = \frac{(1/3)^n}{(z+1/3)^n}$, $n \geq 1$. By Runge's Theorem, for each $n$, there exists a polynomial approximation $p_n(z)$ to $f_n(z)$ such that $|p_n(z)-f_n(z)|<1/(2^n)$. By dividing each $p_n(z)$ with $p_n(0) \neq 0$, we obtain a sequence of polynomials that solves my original question.

Comment: @NgE-Jay I'm not super knowledgeable in this topic, but this looks good to me!